# Firebug architecture

Tags: firefox, firebug, opera, opera-dragonfly

I am looking for an article which covers the architecture of Firebug in detail, showing what the different components in the architecture are, and how they interact during Firefox's running.

Like this:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-dragonfly-architecture/

Answer (score 5):

I have written series or articles called "Extending Firebug" and posted on my blog. This tutorial explains how to write an extension for Firebug as well as Firebug internal architecture and components.

See: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/category/firebug-tutorial/

Honza